# Is it possible for force a square grid in Flot?

Tags: flot

I have a "real space" plot where I'm visualizing planetary orbits. I would like to force square *x*- and *y*-ticks such that I'm looking at a square grid on which the orbits are plotted. I've tried setting `ticks`, `tickSize`, and `minTickSize` all to `1` in the options, but this didn't work. (Note that the tick size doesn't necessarily have to be `1`.) In [flot chart ticks lines not uniform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920108/flot-chart-ticks-lines-not-uniform), there is someone trying to do something similar, but this seems to be pretty specific to EKG charts. Alternatively, is it possible to turn off auto-scaling? I wonder if this would accomplish what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your chart is square and has the same min-/max-values for both axes you get a square grid automatically. No need to set any of the tick options. See this example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2206swqw/).

```
var options = {
    xaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10
    },
    yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10
    }
};
```